# React ES6 alternative for mixins

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm looking for an alternative to React mixins when using ES6 classes.

I would like to inject some functions into my react components, but those functions need React elements.

React ES5 used mixins for that, but React Classes don't support mixins. What's the alternative to mixins in React classes?

Comment: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

Comment: There are other some good points to consider when choosing between ES5 and  ES6 syntax here too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35060571/1879019

Answer (score 7):

Mixins [won't be supported by React in the future](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.imr5m17da). Instead of them you should use Higher-order Components. This [gist](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/ef0bf1f338a7182b6775) provides great explanation of this concept.

Instead of mixing extra functionality into your component you should create a separate one which will provide this functionality to another components.

```
class MyComponent extends React.component {
    render() {
        //...
    }
}

export default extraFunctionality(MyComponent);
```

If you're using Babel with ES7 plugin you can use decorator syntax for that:

```
@extraFunctionality
class MyComponent extends React.component {
    render() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: `render` doesn't usually get any argument.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, you're right, edited my answer. Usually new functionality is passed via props, that's what I wanted to show through this.

Answer (score 2):

Remember, MyComponent, a JS class, is just syntactic sugar, cause under the hood will be used as a function constructor, so with that in mind a simple trick would be something like:

```
var MyMixin = require('whatever/path');
class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        MyMixin.call(this); //this line adds the methods
        this.state = {message: 'Hello world'};
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div>{this.state.message}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Then your Mixin module has to export a function with your mixin functions

```
module.exports = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.method1 = function(){
        // do stuff
        self.setState({
            message: "hello again"
        });
    }
    this.method2 = function(){
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous function to wrap one or multiple classes around the `React.Component` class to add extra functionality:

First create the wrapper class with the extras:

**compExtras.jsx**

```
export default superClass => class extends superClass {

  constructor(props) {  // take props from 'MyComp'.
    super(props);
    this.foo = 'some value';
    this.someChildProp = props.bar; // You can use props of 'MyComp'.
  }

  someExtraMethod(x) {
    return [x, this.foo, this.childProp];
  }
};
```

Now create a usual component that extends the `React.Component` with your *extras-class* to inject the extra functionality:

**myComp.jsx**

```
import extras from './compExtras.js';

class MyComp extends extras(React.Component) {  // extend 'React.Component' with 'extras'

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);  // Pass props to the 'extras' class.
    this.qux = 'some value';
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.someExtraMethod('foo'));  // You have access to that method.
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```

If you want to use multiple extensions for a component create your component like this:

```
class MyComp extends extrasOne(extrasTwo(React.Component)) {
```

Just make sure each *extras-class* passes `props` to its parent class with `super(props)`, so every class gets access to `props`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, there could be more safety-guards, but the concept is there. The advantage is that you CAN access functionality provided by the mixin from the original component, which is not possible by using decorators or high order components:

```
var MixinComposer = (ComposedComponent, Mixin) => class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Mixin.prototype).forEach((func) => {
            if (func != 'constructor')
            ComposedComponent.prototype[func] = Mixin.prototype[func]
        })
        this.composed = <ComposedComponent {...this.props} {...this.state}/>
    }
    render() {
        return this.composed;
    }
}

const FooMixin = class {
    foo() { return "foo" }
}

const MyComponent = MixinComposer(class extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>{ this.foo() }</div>)
    }
}, FooMixin)
```